# Hibernate - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'venueType' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'd like to ask a question about how Spring and Hibernate behave. I'm trying to build an object creation page, but after several tries, I'm coming to you asking for your help.

I have an object, Venue, which possesses a reference to another object, VenueType:

**Venue.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VENUE")
public class Venue extends CommonEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "VENUE_TYPE_ID")
private VenueType venueType;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "ADDRESS", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String address;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "TOWN", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String town; (...)
```

**VenueType.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VENUE_TYPE")
public class VenueType extends CommonEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String name; (...)
```

In my controller, I tried to do like other simple classes I have implemented:

**VenueController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/venue")
public class VenueController {

@Autowired
private VenueService service;
@Autowired
private VenueTypeService venueTypeService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("venues", service.findAll());
    return Venue.getViewFolder() + "/" + "listAll";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadCreateVenuePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("venueTypes", venueTypeService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("venue", new Venue());
    return Venue.getViewFolder() + "/" + "create";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createVenue(@ModelAttribute("venue") Venue venue) {
    service.save(venue);
    return "redirect:/venue";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String readVenuePage(@PathVariable("id") String id, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("venueTypes", venueTypeService.findAll());

    Venue venue = service.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    model.addAttribute("venue", venue);
    return VenueType.getViewFolder() + "/" + "update";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateVenue(@ModelAttribute("venue") Venue venue) {
    service.update(venue);
    return "redirect:/venue";
}
```

In my .jsp file, I have a very simple code, didn't even apply CSS to it:

**venue/create.jsp**

```
<body>
<h1>Creating Venue</h1>

<form:form action="./new" method="POST" commandName="venue">
    <form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <br/>

    <form:label path="address">Address</form:label>
    <form:input path="address"/>
    <br/>

    <form:label path="town">Town</form:label>
    <form:input path="town"/>
    <br/>

    <form:label path="postcode">Post Code</form:label>
    <form:input path="postcode"/>
    <br/>

    <form:label path="country">Country</form:label>
    <form:input path="country"/>
    <br/>

    <form:label path="venueType">Venue Type</form:label>
    <form:select path="venueType">
        <form:option value="" label="Select an option"/>
        <form:options items="${venueTypes}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
    </form:select>

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>

</body>
```

When I try to access the '/new' address, then I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'venueType' available as request attribute`. I have come across several SO questions, most were referring to the lack of a commandName / modelAttribute or the addition of a new object to the ModelMap, what I'm doing. If you can help me pinpointing the cause of the problem, I'll be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The 'venue/update.jsp' page is pratically the same as 'venue/create.jsp', but with an extra hidden 'id' field.

Comment: P.S.: If I try to add a plain object for "venueType", like suggested by the exception itself, it stops loading the exception page, but instead of "venue" pages, it loads the corresponding "venueType" pages instead.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to create a plane object and expose it as a `modelAttribute` with a name equals to `commandName`, in your case the `commandName` is venue then add this method to your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("venue")
public Venue plainVenue() {
    return new Venue();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment. The "/new" page works properly, with the addition of an @InitBinder and PropertyEditorSupport, but the "/{id}" updating info page doesn't; it still throws the "venueType" binding exception. Any ideas about that?